# Http interceptor on response not working in angular 5

Tags: angular5, angular-http-interceptors

I want the user to be automatically logged out if any api returns a 401 error response.And to do that I am intercepting every request and as soon as the error code comes 401 I am clearing the jwt token in my local storage and auth guard prevents the user from jumping to that route.But after implementing the interceptor(examples are very less for this and no mention in the docs as well) I am unable to hit any HTTP request.Below is my code.Thanks in advance.

```
import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ResponseInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        }, (err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                // do error handling here
                console.log('and the error is ');
                console.log(err)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it goes with error why you need to ***track*** every request if you could only ***catch*** needed?

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        catchError((err:string, caught:Observable<any>)=>this.handleHttpClientError(err, caught))
    );
}

handleHttpClientError(error: any, caught: Observable<any>)
{
    if(error.status == 401){
        ... your logic here ... 
    }
    return new EmptyObservable<Response>();
    // or return Observable.throw('Auth error');
}
```

Comment: Hi,Can you give the implementation of the catch error function?

Comment: `import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';`

Comment: Thanks a tonn yo.Although Observable.throw() is deprecated I used ErrorObservable.create('Auth error');   and then import statement was import {ErrorObservable} from 'rxjs/observable/ErrorObservable';
But great help yo.Someone give this man a cookie!